# Which word family of 'satisfy' should be use in this question?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, exam-questions, word-form

> I am so ______ with your report. Surely, you can do better. **(SATISFY)**

I'm just wondering which one is correct to use in this sentence above, satisfied or dissatisfied?

Firstly, I answered 'satisfied'. Then, after I took a look at it again. It seems to me that both of them is acceptable. But in the assignment key, it says the correct answer is only 'satisfied'. Can anyone gives me a explanation on this?

Comment: If the speaker were satisfied, the second sentence *maybe* could be "Still, I'm sure you can do even better." But even that would undercut the first sentence, especially considering the "so".

Answer (score 2):

> in the assignment key, it says the correct answer is only 'satisfied'

The explanation is that the assignment key is **wrong**.

(1) satisfied is not the **only** possible answer from a grammatical point of view.

(2) The context given by the second sentence is that the person could do better. If that is true then the report is imperfect. Clearly the boss/manager would be dissatisfied with a less than perfect report.

Comment: I think it's important to note that the "so" indicates that the boss is very satisfied with the report. If it wasn't there, "satisfied" could mean "it's acceptable, but I think you could do better". (Well, if there was an although... still I think the "so" is a bit of a clue)